Dynamic branch creation for collapsibleTree library
I have this tree
yggdrasil <- collapsibleTree(
  id = "tree",
  data_df, 
  hierarchy = c("Tactic", "ID", "Tactic"),
  inputId = "node",
  collapsed = TRUE,
  width = 1000,
  height = 1000,
  zoomable = TRUE
)

and you will notice that in the hierarchy there is a repetition.
now ideally the user experience would be like so
user chooses a tactic -> the associated techniques appear to the user, he/she choose one -> then all Tactics available open again minus all the data linked to the technique selected
now as you have realised the more nodes you choose the fewer options you get by depth level meaning eventually a single node will appear.
but in order to do this, I need when a node is clicked to be able to update the data frame in real-time and for the tree not to regenerate as a whole but just to generate the new branch with the updated data frame data.
The filtering and data handling of this is not the issue, the main issue is how to place that data in the visualization.
research tells me that it has something to do with the control list and the expand argument of the collapsibleTree library and the use of reactive data and parent-children relationships (which idk if I can totally apply parent-children relationships to this because some data might repeat at certain levels, I am unsure if that is an issue a few of the data has a many to many relationship)
I thank you in advance for reading this post and welcome any advice.
kind regards.
I hope this example will sum up what I mean.
I apologise for being unable to share the actual dataset I am using, not only is it big but it is also part of an ongoing research.


Can you provide a reproducible example? I don't have a tree dataset handy to create a collapsible tree and try to understand your commentary. Providing a dataset will help me help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example
